# MDX sum over various sets

Tags: sum, set, mdx

I have a datacube with a dimension of a large number of academic courses.  I would like to group the courses (create a set) by the name of the course (using filter and Inst), so that I can calculate some aggregate statistics.   i.e. I would ultimately like a list of the number of people doing courses with those groupings (split later by their home geography).

I have four measures, which include

```
[Measures].[Achievements]
[Measures].[Starts]
[Measures].[Enrolments]
[Measures].[Leavers]
```

I have managed to make two sets:

```
CREATE SET [MyDataCube].[BA] AS
    {FILTER(
    [Aim].[Aim Title].[Aim Title].Members,
    (InStr(1, [Aim].[Aim Title].CurrentMember.NAME, "BA ") <> 0) 
        )
        }

GO

CREATE SET [MyDataCube].[BSc] AS
    {FILTER(
    [Aim].[Aim Title].[Aim Title].Members,
    (InStr(1, [Aim].[Aim Title].CurrentMember.NAME, "BSc") <> 0) 
        )
        }
```

And then I can query a single set:

```
SELECT   
NON EMPTY [AccessCourses] DIMENSION PROPERTIES MEMBER_NAME ON ROWS,
NON EMPTY Hierarchize({DrilldownLevel({[Geography - Learner Home].[Learner Home].[All]})}) DIMENSION PROPERTIES MEMBER_NAME ON COLUMNS

FROM [MyDataCube]
```

But how can I get a table with [Geography - Learner Home].[Learner Home].[All] on the rows, with a sum of all [Bsc] and [BA] courses on the columns, like:

[image: desired set output]

I would like to do this for [Measures].[Starts].

Comment: Hi Lisa - Rows should be easy - just use `[Geography - Learner Home].[Learner Home].MEMBERS` ?

Comment: For the columns you need to combine those sets you've created somehow - in my answer I've used Aggregate and not bothered including a measure in the calculated member - that way what ever measure you choose it should adjust irrespective as to whether it is a count or a sum

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following maybe:

```
WITH 
MEMBER [Aim].[Aim Title].[All].[BA] AS
  AGGREGATE(
   [BA]
  )
MEMBER [Aim].[Aim Title].[All].[BSc] AS
  AGGREGATE(
   [BSc]
  )
SELECT   
NON EMPTY 
[Geography - Learner Home].[Learner Home].MEMBERS ON ROWS,
NON EMPTY 
{
  [Aim].[Aim Title].[All].[BA]
 ,[Aim].[Aim Title].[All].[BSc]
} ON COLUMNS
FROM [MyDataCube]
WHERE  [Measures].[Starts];
```